# UIButton text is flashing the "old" text before it updates to the new text

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a peculiar issue.  I have a button that is displayed twice during a video that initially has the title of "Skip Intro" and later on when it reappears it has the title of "Skip Recap".  However, when the button appears for the second time (ie. "Skip Recap"), the button initially flashes on the video as "Skip Intro" and then changes to "Skip Recap".

Here is the code I'm using:

```
- (void)showBreakButton:(NSString *)buttonText
{
    NSString *skipBreakButtonText = BMStringInApplicationLanguageForKey(buttonText);
    [self.skipBreak setTitle:skipBreakButtonText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.skipBreak.hidden = NO;
}

- (void)hideBreakButton
{
    self.skipBreak.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)setupSkipBreakButton
{
    UIImage *skipBreak = [UIImage bm_imageWithBundlePath:BMVideoPlayerControlRackViewSkipBreakImageName];

    [self.skipBreak setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(3.0, -32, 3.0, 0.0)];
    [self.skipBreak setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(3.0, 0.0, 3.0, -155.0)];

    [self.skipBreak setImage:skipBreak forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.skipBreak.backgroundColor = [[UIColor bm_colorWithHexString:BMVideoPlayerDefaultColor]
                                                   colorWithAlphaComponent:1.0f];
    [self.skipBreak addTarget:self action:@selector(skipBreakButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

The "setupSkipBreakButton" is called initially to initialize the button.  The "hideBreakButton" is called after the first button appears (ie. Skip Intro) and then "showBreakButton" is called with a new string so that the button can change to "Skip Recap".

How do I get the button text to show up smoothly without any indication that there was "old" text there?

Comment: Try adding a ```[self.skipBreak setTitle:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];``` to the ```hideBreakButtton``` message.

Comment: Where do you set the title of the button to `"Skip Intro"` and `"Skip Recap"` ?

Comment: Did vote to close it, because it lacks debugging details - see @koen question - how is the button created, where and how do you set titles, ...? Once you update the question I'll retract my vote.

Comment: I figured out the solution.  I just used: 

    [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
      [self.skipBreakButton setTitle:skipBreakButtonText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [self.skipBreakButton layoutIfNeeded];
    }];

Comment: @JFortYork You can add your solution as an answer.